# Make section links in the table of contents point to the top of section‘s page

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

When I click on 3.8 in the [`hyperref` manual](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf), I go to the top of the page where 3.8 is, whatever the zoom level I have. But the default `hyperref` behaviour is to link to the section name. How can I achieve the first one?

I would like also to configure that option only for `\section`s and not for `\sub`..., `\subsub`..., etc.

So in this MWE's ToC A and B should link to the same point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{A}
A is this.
\subsection{A subsec}
Text.
\section{B}
B is this.
\end{document}
```

[This issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162087/locking-boxes-vertical-position) may be related.

Comment: That's weird. I don't get this beahviour; ToC hyperlinks always direct me to the corresponding section and not to the top of the page (using Evince or Acrobat Reader). Which viewer do you use?

Comment: I may have not explained it properly, an erased answer said the same. What I want is to link to the top of the page, not to the section.